# Migrating SharePoint Features from WSS 3.0 to SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, wss-3.0, migration, solution-package

I try to Migrate a SharePoint 2003 (WSS 3.0) to SharePoint 2010. 
I do it with the detach database method.

After I run the test-spcontentdatabase to the restored contentdatabase. I get some errors like that

> Category        : MissingFeature
>   Error           : True
>   UpgradeBlocking : False
>   Message         : Database [WSS_CONTENT_SP30] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id =  [448e1394-5e76-44b4-9e1c-169b7a389a1b].  Remedy : The feature with Id 448e1394-5e76-44b4-9e1c-169b7a389a1b is referenced  in the database [WSS_CONTENT_SP30], but is not installed on the current farm. The missing  feature may cause up grade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the feature and restart upgrade if necessary.

Then I looked into the FEATURES Folder and copy the correspondending features (folders with the containing xml files) into the SharePoint 2010 FEATURES Folder.

After the I run the test again. But I got the same Warnings. Must I activate the copied features manually by myself? Or what did I wrong?

Comment: Yes it's a Foundation 2010 Server.

Comment: I have update my response. Hope it helps now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feature with id `448e1394-5e76-44b4-9e1c-169b7a389a1b` is part of Project Tracking Workspace application template for WSS 3.0 solution provided by Microsoft. It can [downloaded](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1493) from the Microsoft site. So, just install the ProjectTrackingWorkspace.wsp and run the upgrade again.

[image]

Happy SharePointing!

Comment: So If I have som other References like "75a0fea7-c54f-46b9-86b1-2e103a8fedba" That maps to a Feature Called TSAimage. then I must run stsadm -o installfeature -name TSAimage?

Comment: `75a0fea7-c54f-46b9-86b1-2e103a8fedb` is also provided by Microsoft in `ApplicationTemplateCore.wsp` and can easily be downloaded: http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=5922037. `ApplicationTemplateCore.wsp` is pre-req to `ProjectTrackingWorkspace.wsp`. Read instructions on MS site